# how do i get all .csv files from a folder for the present day using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Scan folder and list only .csv files which are created on that particular day.

```
option explicit
dim fileSystem, folder, file, path, myDate
path = "C:\vbs"
Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
myDate =  dateadd("d", -1, FormatDateTime(Now, 2))
Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(path)
for each file in folder.Files
  if file.DateCreated > myDate then
    WScript.Echo file.Name & " created at " & file.DateCreated
    If UCase(filesystem.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "csv" then
      Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
  End If
next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
If UCase(filesystem.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "csv" then
```

transforms the extension to uppercase, but then compares it to a lowercase "csv".

[DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)'s third parameter should be a date; Now (a date) shouldn't be converted to a string.

Comment: `DateAdd` works with both dates and date strings. However, since he wants just the date he should simply use `DateAdd("d", -1, Date)` instead of transforming the output of `Now` into a string with just the date portion.